# How to update "inventory_level" of product by sku id in Bigcommerce?

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I am trying to update the inventory level of a products but unfortunately not getting success.Here is my code.
I want to update product's "inventory_level"  but enable to do so..

```
<?php

require "bigcommerce.php";
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;


Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'https://store-nos85a.mybigcommerce.com/',
    'username' => 'admin',
    'api_key' => '4b7c4bba19f290a728e00be6ae7133cda71f477b'
    ));

Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);
            $product = Bigcommerce::getProduct(76); 
            print_r($product->skus);
                       foreach($product->skus as $sku)
                        {
                           
                            if($sku->id==5)
                                {
                              $fields = array("inventory_level"=>112);
                              Bigcommerce::updateProduct(76,$fields);
                                }
                            echo "id :  ".$sku->id;
                            echo " Invntory Level: ".$sku->inventory_level."<br/>";
                            echo " SKU : ".$sku->sku."<br/>";
                           
                        }
                                                    
           
?>
```

Here `Bigcommerce::updateProduct(76,$field);` is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am trying to do the same thing (different programming language).  I have a call into their support.  It seems like you still must reference the product_id.

You cannot update simply by SKU. You must know the product_id.  I got around this by requesting all products and loading the response into an array (product_id, sku, etc.).  I then read thru the array, get the quantity from our system using the SKU, and post (PUT) the inventory_level using the associated product_id.

IMHO this is a huge oversight on their part.  Who cares what the product_id is on the website?

I have asked for an enhancement that allows updating by SKU.

Comment: I've contacted them about this issue too. They didn't seem too interested in fixing this quickly (or anything else). So, we implemented the same solution.

Comment: yeah I also contacted them about this bug but dont think they will change these things in near future.We have to update "inventory_level" just by product_id and not by sku's :(

Answer (score 8):

No need to download ALL products, why not retrieve JUST the product that has the sku you need?

```
GET: /api/v2/products?sku=sku-that-I'm-interested-in
```

parse the response for the id (that's the product ID for the product with that SKU)

Then do a PUT using that product ID.

Comment: okay it seems almost alright..I will do it that way..Thanks a lot .. :)

Comment: I agree with this answer, iterate over your SKU's, and get the ID's from the SKU's, then updateProduct() on the resulting ID.

I can provide a pure cURL answer that might be easier to implement/understand if needed. Though this answer seems straightforward.

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately when dealing with Products where every Product Option has a different SKU and a separate inventory levels.